# How to export relation links between issues to CSV in YouTrack 6.5

Tags: youtrack

There is very nice and simple way to export all tickets from Youtrack to CSV: `/issues` page -> Reports -> Issues in CSV.

Unfortunately is does not contain any relations between tickets: `depends on`, `parent of` and etc. It is possible to get these links [using REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD65/Export+Links), but I'm looking for a solution that minimize programming (which fears managers).
Is it possible to export relations using built-in functionality?

*Reason why I need to have these links along with tickets is that managers want to draw calendar plans using MS Project or custom Excel spreadsheet and they need to know blocking dependencies.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting links in CSV is not possible. I hope that being able to view a gantt chart directly in YouTrack will relieve your managers: https://blog.jetbrains.com/youtrack/2016/01/10-most-wanted-features-in-youtrack/